# how to print indian languages in ESC/POS printer? how to encoding?

Tags: thermal-printer, codepages, escpos, qz-tray

I’m using  Qz-tray ESC/POS printer.

printer print the Tamil characters like ????????.

Some people say I need to enable encoding the Indian character code page.

How to find the Tamil language code page number?

Sample code:

```java
this.get_dashes('\x2D', 48) + '\x0A',
    '**THANK YOU ! VISIT AGAIN**' + '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x31'+'\x1b' + '\x2D' + '\x49'+'\n', // center align
    '\x1B' +'\x2D' + '\x49',
    this.get_dashes('\x2D',48) + '\x0A',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Epson, the [ESC/P character code table for Tamil is `68`](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_charcode_en/index.php?content_id=78).  Whether or not your printer can recognize this is going to be hardware dependant.

Unfortunately, I [can't find a similar codepage for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html), so you'll need to continue to use hex sequences in your JavaScript code.

```js
// Use strict 8-bit encoding
var config = qz.configs.create("Printer Name", { encoding: 'ISO-8859-1' });

var data = [
   /* Toggle Tamil in ESCPOS */
   '\x1B' + '\x74' + '\x44',   // ESC t 68 = Page 68 [Tamil]

   /* Sample Tamil text (must be hex, Java can't understand this */
   this.get_dashes('\x2D',48) + '\x0A',
   '**THANK YOU ! VISIT AGAIN**' + '\x1B' + '\x61' + '\x31'+'\x1b' + '\x2D' + '\x49'+'\n', //center align
   '\x1B' +'\x2D' + '\x49',
   this.get_dashes('\x2D',48) + '\x0A',
   // ...
];
```